# Refactoring two similar swift switch statements

Tags: swift, switch-statement, refactoring

I have a couple of switch statements where I initially convert a some JSON values to a user-friendly name (convertCategoryValueToName).

Later on, in a different part of the app, I need to undertake some checks based on user-friendly name, and I have written a corresponding switch to convert the name back to it's original value (convertCategoryNameToValue).

The switch statements are long, and I'm not happy with the repetition. Is there a way to refactor this work into one Switch?

Shortened switch examples...

```
func convertCategoryValueToName(category: String) -> String? {
    var categoryName: String?
    switch category {
    case "dessert":
        categoryName = "Desserts"
    case "drink":
        categoryName = "Drinks"
    default:
        break
    }
    return categoryName
}

func convertCategoryNameToValue(category: String) -> String? {
    var categoryValue: String?
    switch category {
    case "Desserts":
        categoryValue = "dessert"
    case "Drinks":
        categoryValue = "drink"
    default:
        break
    }
    return categoryValue
}
```

Comment: What about using an `Enum`? But you shouldn't use `convertCategoryNameToValue`. Your model and the view (what you show to the user, the category "human readable/userfriendly with an uppercase and such) aren't the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use an `enum`.

```
enum Category: String {
    case dessert = "Desserts"
    case drink = "Drinks"
}
```

Then use `Category.dessert.rawValue` to display the *"user-friendly name"* on the UI and use the `enum` cases for everything else in your code.

Comment: Using an enum is perfect. Can't say why that didn't occur to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
let dict = ["dessert": "Desserts",
            "drink"  : "Drinks"]

func convertCategoryValueToName(category: String) -> String? {
    return dict[category]
}

func convertCategoryNameToValue(category: String) -> String? {
    return dict.keys.first(where: { $0 == category})
}
```